# html file content is not displayed while adding custom rule for Php in SonarQube

Tags: php, html, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.3 and added a custom rule for Php. I deployed the plugin correctly. The problem is that when I click on the rule in UI, It only displays the rule's definition (key, tag, description...) it does not display the description which I wrote in an html file.

Do I need to precise the existence of this html file somewhere in my plugin?

Is there a solution to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Html file with rule description should be in the folder `org/sonar/l10n/php/rules/<rule repository name>`

see example [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/master/php-custom-rules/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/php/rules/custom/S1.html).

Or you can provide description through annotation property. See comment [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/master/php-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/php/checks/OtherForbiddenFunctionUseCheck.java#L52).

Comment: thnks, but my error was something else. Actually the rule key should be the name of the rule description file (in org/sonar/l10n/php/rules/<rule repository) which was not the case in my code